# Optimizing a Summoner w Synthesist Archetype using Natural Weapons for max DPS

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization, summoner, natural-weapon

With goals of Max DPS to keep up with a Min/maxed wizard and Dwarven Fighter, is this an optimal build?  This is my first venture into a natural weapons build.

### What enhancements should I have?

- I need something that is a free or immediate action so not to spend several rounds buffing

---

### Existing build: Is it optimized for DPS?

Suli ***Level 1***
Outsider Summoner w Synthesist Archetype

Power Attack -1/+2
Bite +3/ d6+5   (Add d6 elemental w swift)
Claw (x2) +3/ d6+5

**Tactics**:
Swift action elemental assault and move to optimal charge for next round.
Next round pounce — full attack after charge.

**Statistics**:
Feats: Power Attack

**Special Abilities**:
- Improved damage claws
- Elemental assault
- Pounce

Comment: The problem I see with this question is the following: You want to do equal damage to a min/maxed wizard. Assuming you mean an optimized wizard then every synthesist will deal that much damage as an optimized wizard will not go for dealing damage but for winning combats which wizards can do much easier than just through dealing damage.

Comment: The attack bonuses seem to be wrong. As written you have +3 normal size but +7 when enlarged. Enlarge person gives you -1 to hit, +2 Strength which balance out. So why do you get +4 to hit when enlarged?

Comment: I also see four different questions: is this build optimised? which magic items should I use? which feat tree should I take? what enhancements should I use?

Comment: @Umbranus OP didn't say they expected to beat out the wizard, only keep up. And if the DM is prone to long encounters or denying suitable rest, there is still plenty of room for martial PC's to be viable. Consider it 'maxing' sustain

Comment: The bonuses for enlarged eidolon are different.  "An eidolon grows in size, becoming Large. The eidolon gains a +8 bonus to Strength, a +4 bonus to Constitution, and a +2 bonus to its natural armor. It takes a –2 penalty to its Dexterity. This size change also gives the creature a –1 size penalty to its AC and on attack rolls, a +1 bonus to its CMB and CMD, a –2 penalty on Fly skill checks, and a –4 penalty on Stealth skill checks. If the eidolon has the biped base form, it also gains 10-foot reach."
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons

Comment: The part you quote is from the large evolution. In your question it sounded as if you wanted to use a spell to enlarge. In that case the spell's rules would be relevant, not the evolution. "Tactics: Casts **enlarge person** and swift action elemental assault. Then pounce — full attack after charge."

Comment: Please use comments to respond to comments rather than using flags. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're maxing damage, it is going to be a non-grapple build because you cannot do iterative/full natural attacks in grapple. It's not that grapple dps builds can't be made, but they are extremely feat heavy and based on having one source of high damage, not multiple natural attacks.

Focus on anything that allows movement (Step up, etc) or if you want to select a maneuver, choose either improved/greater disarm or trip. They both replace melee attacks, so you can still strike with your other natural weapons. A disarmed opponent provokes Attacks of Opportunity and does not threaten unless they have Improved Unarmed Strike; a prone target is flat-footed.

[Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists) (+1: 4kg, then up) replaces Greater Magic Fang; alternately, Magic Fang (and Greater) can be Permanancy'd for less money if you're willing to accept the chance of being dispelled.

The [Impact](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/impact) trait (+2) increases effective weapon size by one, but probably isn't the best replacement for Strong Jaw since that gives effective 2 sizes.

Unfortunately, the cheapest/earliest access to itemized Haste is [Boots of Speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-speed) for 12kg. You could request that your Wizard cast it on you when necessary, although you Fighter would probably also want that treatment.

Comment: Playing the character always sorts out a lot of theoretical issues and miscalculated bonuses.  Thanks for all the answers.